# LWJGL crashing at startup

Tags: java, linux, lwjgl

I started learning how to use LWJGL library and wrote a simple display program, but it just crashes right away. I'm using Linux Mint

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at DisplayExample.start(DisplayExample.java:10)
    at DisplayExample.main(DisplayExample.java:29)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.getAvailableDisplayModes(LinuxDisplay.java:951)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.LinuxDisplay.init(LinuxDisplay.java:738)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.<clinit>(Display.java:138)
    ... 2 more

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Here's the code I wrote:

```
import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;

import java.io.File;

public class DisplayExample {
    public void start(){
        try{
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(800,600));
            Display.create();
        }
        catch(LWJGLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }

        while(!Display.isCloseRequested()){
            Display.update();
        }
        Display.destroy();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + "linux");
        DisplayExample d = new DisplayExample();
        d.start();
    }
}
```

thanks in advance for replies!

---

Here's the output of `xrandr -q`

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: You may wanna join [slack](https://lwjgl.slack.com/) and ask also there, maybe spasi can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LWJGL uses [xrandr](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xrandr.1.html) under the hood to get the screen resolutions [by parsing `xrandr -q` command output](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/opengl/XRandR.java#L72).

Check that `xrandr` is installed and `xrandr -q` returns valid output on the machine that runs your Java code. Then check your logs for [`Exception in XRandR.populate()` message](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl/blob/master/src/java/org/lwjgl/opengl/XRandR.java#L146) which will tell you why LWJGL failed to get the resolutions.

Comment: im really sorry for ignorance, but how do i check the logs? i checked the build logs through intellij and the build was fine

Comment: See [Debug mode on LWJGL wiki](https://github.com/LWJGL/lwjgl3-wiki/wiki/2.5.-Troubleshooting#debug-mode). TBH LWJGL is open source so you can easily [debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-your-first-java-application.html) this problem.

Comment: i did as you said and i got the following: "[LWJGL] Exception in XRandR.populate(): Cannot run program "xrandr": error=2, No such file or directory"

which is wierd since i do have xrandr (the command works in the shell)

Comment: Either way you know the root cause. It's impossible to tell why this happens without having more information about your OS setup.

Comment: i see. what details are essentials?